# Adding new columns & variable rows to SQL select query as output and perform arithmetic operations in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am writing a SQL query for selecting data from a table and also Adding new columns & variable rows to SQL select query as output and perform arithmetic operations in it.

So the select query brings out the required result, but I need to add a column `PERIOD_TYPE` WHICH WILL CONTAIN `DAY, WTD, MTD, YTD` on the basis of below criteria :-

**DAY** = @date_using (E.g. '2020-12-22')

**WTD** = Week's Starting Monday Date of @date_using To @date_using (e.g. 21 DEC 2020 TO 22 DEC 2020)

**MTD** = Month's Starting Monday Date of @date_using To @date_using (e.g. 1 DEC 2020 TO 22 DEC 2020)

**YTD** = Year's Starting Monday Date of @date_using To @date_using (e.g. 1 JAN 2020 TO 22 DEC 2020)

Also, One more column is to be added `SALES_LY_USD` that which will show the sum of Column's data.

**So, in that `SALES_LY_USD` it will show Sum of `A.TY_SALES` as below criteria :-**

**DAY** : Sum of `A.TY_SALES` for  '2020-12-22'

**WTD** : Sum of `A.TY_SALES` for (Week's Starting Monday Date of @date_using To @date_using) (e.g. Sum of`A.TY_SALES` for 21 DEC 2020 TO 22 DEC 2020)

**MTD** = Sum of `A.TY_SALES` for (Month's Starting Monday Date of @date_using To @date_using) (e.g. Sum of`A.TY_SALES` for 1 DEC 2020 TO 22 DEC 2020)

**YTD** = Sum of `A.TY_SALES` for (Year's Starting Monday Date of @date_using To @date_using) (e.g. Sum of`A.TY_SALES` for 1 JAN 2020 TO 22 DEC 2020)

So, the example output table should be :-

| COUNTRY | PERIOD_TYPE | SALES_LY_USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | DAY | 15 |
| ID | WTD | 30 |
| ID | MTD | 300 |
| ID | YTD | 3600 |

I was writing below codes but I am unable fetch these 4 above shared different Period_Types in Period_Type columns and also unable to use them to show the sum in SALES_LY_USD column.

```
DECLARE @date DATE=DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
DECLARE @sale_date_ly DATE
DECLARE @date_using DATE = '2020-12-07'
DECLARE @DAY_PERIOD_TYPE_TY DATE
DECLARE @WTD_PERIOD_TYPE_TY DATE
DECLARE @MTD_PERIOD_TYPE_TY DATE
DECLARE @YTD_PERIOD_TYPE_TY DATE

SET @sale_date_ly = (select last_year_same_dd_date from analyse.HKMN_MD_TIME where display_date=@date_using)

SET @DAY_PERIOD_TYPE_TY = (select Date from [dbo].[DimDate]  where date=@date_using)

SET @WTD_PERIOD_TYPE_TY  = (SELECT CONCAT (Convert(date,DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,@date_using),0)), ' To ', @date_using )

SET @MTD_PERIOD_TYPE_TY  = (SELECT CONCAT ((select FirstDayOfMonth from [dbo].[DimDate] where date=@date_using ), ' To ', @date_using )

SET @YTD_PERIOD_TYPE_TY  = (SELECT CONCAT ((select FirstDayOfYear from [dbo].[DimDate] where date=@date_using ), ' To ', @date_using )


SELECT  

A.COUNTRY As COUNTRY,
@sale_date_ly As PERIOD_TYPE ,
sum(B.TY_SALES)  AS SALES_LY_USD

from [SE].[SHAPE] A
INNER JOIN [SE].[LF_SHAPE] B
ON A.COUNTRY=B.COUNTRY
```

Comment: `JOIN` with a `SUM (CASE WHEN Date >= FirstDayOfYear THEN TY_SALES END)` and another similar `SUM` for each period you need

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks.. But I am also wondering over how to find the Period Type according to the criteria and show it in table